# Can I initialise multiple variables at the beginning of a Go/Golang if block using multiple functions with multiple return values?

Tags: if-statement, go, initialization

I'm trying to use two functions to initialise variables inside an if block.
Both functions return a bool value and an error.
I have tried the following, but with no success. Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do?

```golang
func returnAValueAndError() (bool, error) {
    return true, nil
}

func alsoReturnAValueAndError() (bool, error) {
    return false, nil
}

if a, _ := returnAValueAndError(), b, _ := alsoReturnAValueAndError(); a || b {
//    this gives me
//    ./prog.go:16:42: syntax error: unexpected :=, expecting {
}

if a, _ := returnAValueAndError(); b, _ := alsoReturnAValueAndError(); a || b {
//    this gives me
//    ./prog.go:16:42: syntax error: cannot use b, _ := alsoReturnAValueAndError() as value
//    ./prog.go:17:38: syntax error: unexpected newline, expecting comma or }
}

if a, _, b, _ := returnAValueAndError(), alsoReturnAValueAndError(); a || b {
//    this gives me
//    ./prog.go:16:16: assignment mismatch: 4 variables but returnAValueAndError returns 2 values
//    ./prog.go:16:39: multiple-value returnAValueAndError() in single-value context
//    ./prog.go:16:67: multiple-value alsoReturnAValueAndError() in single-value context
}
```

Comment: You already seem to know the answer. What is your question?

Comment: @Flimzy: My question was "Can it be done? If so, how?" Burak's answer below mentions "simple statement"s, which I was then able to search for and find a definition, which I then added as a comment in order to improve the quality of the answer.  At the time, it wasn't long enough since the question had been asked for me to be allowed to mark the question as answered. What makes you think I knew the answer when I asked the question? What have I done to merit a downvote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that. The condition can be preceded by a simple statement (not multiple statements):

https://golang.org/ref/spec#If_statements

Comment: I'm not sure why, but my previous comment here was removed. For any future readers, a discussion of 'simple statements' can be found here: https://medium.com/golangspec/simple-statement-notion-in-go-b8afddfc7916